Use GCC to compile UWP DLL
I'm trying to compile a Godot 3.x application's GDNative module for UWP.
Unfortunately, this fails and the result is always a native Win32 DLL that won't load in the constrained UWP environment.
Is there any option inside x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc like the /ZW flag one would pick on Windows?

The /ZW flag is specific to MSVC and enables the C++/CX Language Extensions. This is not required for UWP development, but they were the original solution for consuming Windows Runtime APIs which are required for many UWP apps.
You can build using MSVC without /ZW or clang/LLVM using the C++/WinRT Projections which are C++ headers generated directly from the .winmd files. This requires C++17 language support, and I'm not sure that they have been tested with MinGW/GCC. See Microsoft Learn.
That said, I doubt the GNU C Runtime on Windows would pass the requirements for UWP publishing via WACK in any case. You can use clang-cl because it makes use of the MSVC Runtime which is supported via a framework package.

Godot does support targeting UWP.

